# Create a member function pointer to a function that returns std::pair

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, std-pair

I want to access a function that returns a pair through a pointer that is defined according to input at runtime.

Example code:

```
int main() {
    struct Math::strinfo si; // This was what caused the problem - See answer and question edit

    typedef std::pair<double, string> (*FuncChosen)(struct strinfo *si, double first, double second);
    FuncChosen p = Math::calcSpeed;
}
```

calcSpeed looks like this and is in the namespace 'Math':

```
namespace Math {
    struct strinfo
    {
        string strformula;
        string chosenCalcStr;
    };

    std::pair<double, string> calcSpeed(struct strinfo *si, double distance, double time)
    {
        si->strformula = "Speed = distance / time";
        si->chosenCalcStr = "Speed";
        return make_pair(distance/time, std::to_string(distance) + " / " + std::to_string(time));
    }
}
```

I can't assign FuncChosen p to calcSpeed because it has an 'lvalue of type std::pair'.
The code above worked fine when calcSpeed returned a double - is this method incompatible with functions that return a pair and if so are there any workarounds that don't involve changing the return type of the function from a pair to something else?

The reason I want to assign the pointer at runtime is so that I can choose whether to use calcSpeed or a number of other functions with same parameters and return types according to input and the only way to do this without conditionals is by this method (I think).

Thanks in advance,

Edit:
Full error code FYI:

```
SDT_Test/main.cpp:63:16: Cannot initialize a variable of type 'FuncChosen' (aka 'std::pair<double,   string> (*)(struct strinfo *, double, double)') with an lvalue of type 'std::pair<double, string> (struct strinfo *, double, double)': type mismatch at 1st parameter ('struct strinfo *' (aka 'strinfo *') vs 'struct strinfo *' (aka 'Math::strinfo *'))
```

Edit 2:

I forgot to include a line of my code that would have given away the problem. The answer below shows the problem was with 'struct strinfo *si' in the typedef - should be 'Math::strinfo *si'.

Comment: Are you missing std namespace for `std::string` in pair? Why not to typedef std::pair as well?

Comment: I have 'using std::string' at the top of the program - What do you mean by your second question? That is the online line in the program that returns an error. I will add the full error message to the question if that helps clarify the problem.

Comment: @exitc0de - The issue, and clue to the answer is in the error message.  You have an issue with the first parameter `strInfo`.

Comment: I mean `typedef std::pair<double, string> sometype;` and then use `sometype`

Comment: Wow, I didn't see the 'type mismatch at 1st parameter ('struct strinfo *''. Sorry - that was a stupid mistake. Thanks for your help - I clarified in the question but I did not see this in the error until you pointed it out (Xcode makes it difficult to read the full error message and when I managed to paste it in I didn't read it). Again, sorry for being stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring a new type named `strinfo` in your `typedef`

```
typedef std::pair<double, string> (*FuncChosen)(struct strinfo *si, double first, double second);
//                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
// that's a declaration of new type, not Math::strinfo
```

The error would've been obvious if you'd omitted the unnecessary `struct` keyword in the `typedef`. Change it to

```
typedef std::pair<double, std::string> (*FuncChosen)(Math::strinfo *si, double first, double second);
```

or the (IMHO) more readable version

```
using FuncChosen = std::pair<double, std::string>(*)(Math::strinfo *si, double first, double second);
```

Comment: That fixed it - updated question with what I did wrong and why I did not see this. Sorry for omitting an important part of my program before the typedef in main. (see my edit)